# "OnChange" functionality for <html:select> field is not working

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript function is not working. I didn't any alert messages on my web page.  Please help me...
**This is my Html code**

```
function checkCompletedProjectStatus() {
  alert("Helloo");
  var dropdownType = document.getElementById("status");
  var current_value = dropdownType.options[dropdownType.selectedIndex].value;
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("extendedHours");
  dropdown[1].style.display = "block";
  dropdown[2].style.display = "block";
  dropdown[3].style.display = "block";
  dropdown[4].style.display = "block";
  dropdown[5].style.display = "block";
  dropdown[6].style.display = "block";
  if (current_value == "Completed") {
    alert("Current Value" + current_value);
    dropdown[1].style.display = "none";
    dropdown[2].style.display = "none";
    dropdown[3].style.display = "none";
    dropdown[5].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<html:select name="status" property="theTasks.status" value="theTasks.status" onchange="checkCompletedProjectStatus(this)">
  <option value="">Select Status</option>
  <option value="Scheduled">Scheduled</option>
  <option value="In progress">In progress</option>
  <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
  <option value="On hold">On hold</option>
  <option value="Extended">Extended</option>
</html:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following alerts out the selected value (I've removed the code not being utilised)

HTML:

```
<select id="status" property="theTasks.status" value="theTasks.status" onchange="checkCompletedProjectStatus(this)">
  <option value="">Select Status</option>
  <option value="Scheduled">Scheduled</option>
  <option value="In progress">In progress</option>
  <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
  <option value="On hold">On hold</option>
  <option value="Extended">Extended</option>
<select>
```

Javascript:

```
function checkCompletedProjectStatus(target) {
  var dropdownType = document.getElementById("status");
  var current_value = target.value;

  alert('selected value: '+ current_value);

  if (current_value === "Completed") {
    alert("Completed selected");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But the issue is don't change the <html> tag. It should be <html:select>, if I change it will work. Is there any relevant onchange() for <html:select> field?